# Number of positive integer walks from 0 to b.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, catalan-numbers

It is well known that the number of walks of length $m=2k+1$ starting at $0$ and ending at $0$ of step size $\pm 1$ and always nonnegative is the number of Dyck paths from $(0,0)$ to $(k,k)$ i.e. the $k^{th}$ Catalan number $C_k$.  The following seems like it should be well known but I have been having trouble locating it:  how many walks of length $m=2k+b$ are there starting at $0$ and ending at $b$ of step size $\pm1$ and always nonnegative?  Bonus points for a reference.

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof that the number of nonnegative paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2k,0)$ is $C_k$ that uses reflection through $y=-1$ ? This argument can be easily adjusted to show that the number of nonnegative paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2k+b,b)$ is $\binom{2k+b}{k}-\binom{2k+b}{k-1}$.

Comment: I am not... should that be easy to locate?

Comment: Look for "ballot numbers" or "Catalan triangle".  You will find the values in [OEIS A009766](http://oeis.org/A009766) and sequences linked there

Answer (score 3):

In the latter part of [this article](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/uniwalk.html), I use generating functions to show that the number of walks of length $2k+b$ starting at $0$ and ending at $b$ where no partial sum is negative is
$$
\frac{b+1}{k+b+1}\binom{2k+b}{k}
$$

Comment: Note that $$\frac{b+1}{k+b+1}\binom{2k+b}{k} = \binom{2k+b}{k}-\binom{2k+b}{k-1}$$ which is the [formula cited by tipshoni](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165856/number-of-positive-integer-walks-from-0-to-b#comment381818_165856).

Comment: Do you know Raney's lemma?

Comment: @FrankScience: I [do](http://rsrch.wordpress.com/2011/10/22/raneys-lemma/) now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the completely elementary, though somewhat tricky, argument using reflection:

Let's try to count the number of paths starting at $(0,0)$, ending in $(2k+b,b)$ that are **not** nonnegative:

By reflecting through the line $y=-1$ the part of the path from $(0,0)$ until the first time it goes below the x-axis, we get a bijection between the non-nonegative paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2k+b,b)$ and **all** paths from $(0,-2)$ to $(2k+b,b)$, whose number is clearly $\binom{2k+b}{k-1}$.

So We get that the number of non-nonnegative paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2k+b,b)$ is $\binom{2k+b}{k-1}$, and since the number of all paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2k+b,b)$ is $\binom{2k+b}{k}$, we conclude that the desired number of nonnegative paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2k+b,b)$ is $\binom{2k+b}{k}-\binom{2k+b}{k-1}$ (which is indeed $\frac{b+1}{k+b+1}\binom{2k+b}{k}$)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another proof.

First we consider the following conclusion, which is really George N. Raney's result in *Functional composition patterns and power series reversion*:

If $\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\rangle$ is *any sequence* of integers with $x_j\le1$ *for all* $j$, and with $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m=l>0$, then *exactly* $l$ of the cyclic shifts
$$\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\rangle,\langle x_2,\ldots,x_m,x_1\rangle,\ldots,\langle x_m,x_1,\ldots,x_{m-1}\rangle$$
have *all positive partial sums*.

It can be proved by a simple geometric argument (I don't know how to describe it in English, but you can see an algebraic proof in *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik, EXERCISE 7.13).

Now it's easier to solve your original problem. First we add $+1$ to the beginning of each sequence, to make the partial sums *positive* (and each one with the partial sums *positive* can be deleted the first term to get a sequence with *nonnegative* partial sums, so it's bijection). There're $\binom{2k+b+1}{k+b+1}$ sequences with $k$ occurences of $-1$ and $k+b+1$ occurences of $+1$, and Raney's lemma tells us that exactly $(b+1)/(2k+b+1)$ sequences (Why? See next paragraph) have all partial sums positive. So the answer is
$$\frac{b+1}{2k+b+1}\binom{2k+b+1}{k+b+1}=\frac{b+1}{k+b+1}\binom{2k+b}{k+b}=\frac{b+1}{k+b+1}\binom{2k+b}k$$.

Explanation for $(b+1)/(2k+b+1)$: Construct $N\times(2k+b+1)$ array, where $N=\binom{2k+b+1}{k+b+1}$. Each line is just $2k+b+1$ cyclic shifts of the first term, and the first column is $N$ sequences with $k$ occurences of $-1$ and $k+b+1$ occurences of $+1$. Each row contains exactly one solution, so there're exactly $N$ occurences of solutions. Each solution appears exactly once in each column, so it appears exactly $2k+b+1$ times in the whole array.